# R packages for seasonality analysis

Tags: r, seasonality

What R packages should I install for seasonality analysis?

Comment: Is the OP asking for a way to find the seasonality of a series? In my opinion, that is a quite complex question, and none of the above answers (I think) address that. Please correct me if I am worng, either about the question or the answer.

Comment: It might be better to ask how one performs seasonality analysis in general. That risks being too broad a topic, but, at least it would not be off-topic. In its current form, the question is off-topic because it is asking for help with R, and not help with statistics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to install any packages because this is possible with base-R functions.  Have a look at [the arima function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/arima).

This is a basic function of [Box-Jenkins analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Jenkins), so you should consider reading one of the R time series text-books for an overview; my favorite is Shumway and Stoffer. "[Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387293175)".

Answer (score 8):

Try using the `stl()` function for time series decomposition. It provides a very flexible method for extracting a seasonal component from a time series.

Answer (score 2):

I [build](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seas/)/[published](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cageo.2006.11.011) an R package named `seas` for my [M.Sc. work](https://summit.sfu.ca/item/8338) a few years ago. The package is good for discretizing a time-series over years into seasonal divisions, such as months or 11-day periods. These divisions can then be applied to *continuous variables* (e.g., [temperature](https://web.archive.org/web/20130221070211/http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Seasonal_temperature_140), water levels) or *discontinuous variables* (e.g., [precipitation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130617052327/http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Seasonal_precipitation_141), groundwater recharge rates).